# Скачивание большого объема видеороликов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть несколько тысяч ссылок на видео в Интернете. Необходимо скачать из все **максимально быстро**.

Ранее использовал библиотеку *requests*, однако скачивание длилось очень долго (70 Кб — средний вес файла, а среднее время скачивание 3 секунды, то есть около 25 Кб/с, хотя скорость интернета больше мегабита в секунду). В диспетчере задач график скорости Wi-Fi скачет (то 0, то на долю секунды 1,4 Мб/с).

Как скачать их все с помощью **программы Python**? Может есть способ скачивать их одновременно?

P.S.Слышал про библиотеку *aiohttp*, но примеров работы для моего случая не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это немного поможет.

```py
import threading
import requests
import shutil

url_list= [] # Тут хранятся ссылки на скачивание

def Thread(my_funk):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_funk, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        my_thread.start()

    return wrapper

@Thread # теперь функция будет запускается в новом потоке
def download(url):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(r'E:\Python\exampeles\file' + url , 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)


for url in url_list: #Теперь список запустит почти ОДНОВРЕМЕННО много функций для скачивания
    download(url)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/acer/PycharmProjects/Foxford_download/try.py", line 73, in <module>
    download(url, i)
  File "C:/Users/acer/PycharmProjects/Foxford_download/try.py", line 54, in wrapper
    my_thread.start()
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 847, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread

Comment: А сколько, примерно, вы планируете загружать видео? Можно попробовать сделать следующее: threading.stack_size(64*1024). Если и это не поможет, лучше сделать загрузку асинхронной.

Comment: примерно 10000 файлов (threading.stack_size(64*1024)) не помогло, выдавал ту же ошибку

Comment: Для нескольких тысяч загрузок не подходит, но если качать сотнями, хороший вариант, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вот асинхронный вариант:

```py
import requests
import asyncio
import time
import random
import wget

url_list = ['https://interesno-vse.ru/wp-content/uploads/spokoynoy-nochi-0111.jpg'] * 20

async def wget_download(url):
    wget.download(url, 'E:\\Python\\exampeles\\'+ str(random.randint(1000000,9999999999)) +'.png' )

async def download(url):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(r'E:\\Python\\exampeles\\' + str(random.randint(1000000,9999999999)) +'.png' , 'wb+') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)


async def start_download():
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future( download(url) ) for url in url_list ]
    #tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future( wget_download(url) ) for url in url_list ] # cкачать с помощью wget
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)

ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

srt = time.time()

ioloop.run_until_complete( start_download() )
ioloop.close()

print(time.time() - srt) # Покажет время загрузки
```

Comment: Не работает, причем скорость интернета колеблется в районе от 40 до 80 Кб/с, как будто его ограничивают, и скачивает файлы непонятно куда + не хватает строки import shutil в начале. P.S. он не непонятно куда сохраняет, а не сохраняет вообще, строка if r.status_code == 200:, видимо дает false, потому что, как только я ее убрал, он стал создавать файлы, но пустые и их нельзя открыть

Comment: Здесь нет абсолютно ничего асинхронного. От того, что вы запустите синхронный код модулей requests и wget в раздельных тасках, он не станет асинхронным чудом сам по себе.

Comment: У меня все работает. А пробовал через wget_download()? Напиши в коде: print(r.status_code). 200  это все ок, и значит можно качать, если нет загугли  что значик полученное число. И как ты путь для сохранения прописал у себя?

Comment: В определенную папку на харде, wget_download пробовал, тоже ничего

Comment: Выдает 404, типа такой ссылки нет, видимо где-то в коде ошибка P.S. исправил код, все работает хорошо, но медленно, буду использовать верхний код.